# How to change font color in the title slide of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

So I'm using beamer with the Berlin theme and beaver color. Inside the \institute command within the preamble I have the name of my institution, but I get this white color that cannot be seen at the bottom of the slide:

[image]

How can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the colour like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\institute{test}

\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=red!60!black}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```